# Finding $x$ for which $\sqrt{x+6}<x-6$

Tags: inequality

My method

$x+6 \ge0 $

$\implies x \ge -6$

Squaring both sides would result in

$(x-10)(x-3)>0$

$\implies x \in (-\infty,3) \cup (10, \infty)$

Answer should be $x \in$ $[-6, \infty) \cap ((-\infty,3) \cup (10, \infty))$

So shouldn't the solution be $x \in [-6,3) \cup (10, \infty)$ ?

Wolfram alpha solves the inequality as $x \in (10, \infty)$

I get why  my solution isn't getting the answer when substituting values, but I want to know what the fault in my method is

Comment: Whenever you encounter simple functions, try to think of it's graph once, it helps a lot. Doing algebraically can deceive you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $\sqrt{x+6}<x-6$

Note the RHS requires $x-6>0$, otherwise, if $x-6\le0$, then you get

$$\sqrt{x+6}<0$$

which gives no real solutions.

So your result together with $x-6>0$ will give you the correct answer.

Comment: Oh I can't believe I missed that , thank you :)

Comment: No problem, just be cautious before you do the squaring on both sides :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that $\sqrt{x+6} < x-6 \implies x+6 < (x - 6)^2$ but the reverse implication is not true; instead, $x+6 < (x - 6)^2 \implies (x > 6) \land (\sqrt{x+6} < x-6)$ or $(x < 6) \land (\sqrt{x+6} < 6-x)$. This means that only if $x>6$ is the (squared) inequality you solved equivalent to the one you were trying to solve.

Comment: No, it should be $x>6$, $x$ cannot equal or less than $6$.

Comment: I'm trying to explain what went wrong: the inequality OP derived by squaring is not equivalent to the one they wanted to solve precisely because it *can* imply $x<6$.

Comment: $x+6 < (x - 6)^2 \implies (x \ge 6) \land (\sqrt{x+6} < x-6)$ This step, cannot be $"="$

Comment: No. $x=0$ satisfies the condition of the implication but not its conclusion.

Comment: Or were you just referring to the strictness of the inequality? I've corrected that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145838/discussion-between-mcd-and-mathfail).

Answer (score 1):

In our case squaring of the both sides is not correct.

For example, for $x=1$ we obtain a wrong statement: $\sqrt7<-5$, but after squaring we have $7<25,$ which is true, which says that we got a
redundant solution.

Also, we can solve your inequality by the following way.
$$0<x-6-\sqrt{x+6}=x-10+4-\sqrt{x+6}=x-10+\frac{16-x-6}{4+\sqrt{x+6}}=$$
$$=(x-10)\left(1-\frac{1}{4+\sqrt{x+6}}\right)=\frac{(x-10)\left(3+\sqrt{6+x}\right)}{4+\sqrt{x+6}},$$ which says that our inequality is equivalent to $$x>10.$$